# Swimwear to prevent thigh chafing while swimming in the ocean

Tags: swimming, clothing, sea-swimming

I've recently been swimming in the ocean, and I've been chafing high on my inner thighs. (This isn't chafing related to drying off afterward, or walking around in wet swimwear. It's just happening as I swim—skin-on-skin or skin-on-suit friction.) I've just been wearing swim trunks, which have an inner net. Is there another style of swimwear that would prevent this chafing? (I would like to avoid applying a cream or lubricant if I can.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### A jammer or brief will both be safer and probably prevent chafing issues.

Speedo (and every other competitive swimwear manufacturer) makes “jammers”, which are skin tight and go to just above the knee. Or you could get the classic speedo brief. This should solve the chafing. These will also be safer by virtue of having reduced drag, making swimming a bit easier.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. I got some jammers, which (albeit after only one swim) are making a big difference.